# javascript interval stop on moueover

Tags: javascript

I could not figure out how to stop image intervals when the mouse is over the image.

var myImage = document.getElementById("world");

```
var imageArray = ["imgs/worldGray.png","imgs/worldGreen.png","imgs/worldPink.png", "imgs/worldYellow.png", "imgs/world.png"];//html picture add here
var imageIndex=0;


function changeImage(){
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >=imageArray.length){
        imageIndex =0;
    }
}
var intervalHandle=setInterval(changeImage,5000);
// the problem is in the below fucntions
myImage.onmouseover = function(){
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
}
myImage.onmouseout = function(){
    setInterval(intervalHandle);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I think it's a coding issue.. saying what the actual problem is you are having will let us help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure why you are setting the interval again using the "intervalHandler", and don't think there is such a use.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

You should write

```
intervalHandle=setInterval(changeImage,5000);
```

inside onmouseout handler to make it run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script at the bottom of page. It worked for me